# The constructor Object(Context, int, T[]) is undefined - Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, super

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) but I get the error in the title at the line marked below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class ExpenditureArrayAdapter {

    private final Context context;
    private final Expenditure[] values;

    public ExpenditureArrayAdapter(Context context,Expenditure[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_expenditures, values); <----
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to extend `ArrayAdapter`. Currently your `ExpenditureArrayAdapter` class inherits from `Object`, which has no constructor `Object(Context, int, T[])`.

Change

```
public class ExpenditureArrayAdapter {
```

to

```
public class ExpenditureArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
```

and it should fix your problem.